# How to add custom control shapes to a rig in Maya

Tags: animation, maya, rigging

I find most Maya animation videos has these circle lines to control character part rotation:

[image: Screenshot of 3D character with yellow circles drawn around body parts]

Why does my imported fbx not have these circle lines?

[image: Screenshot of 3D character with overlaid bones but no rigging controls]

Answer (score 0):

In Maya those are controls set up as part of the rig for the character so that the animator can easily move the character around and set keys on the controls and not the geometry. I'm not sure what fbx is (as I am just a student studying animation using Maya), but you might want to google how to create your own controls (creating controls using nurbsCurves and set driven keys or costume attributes), or how to move your fbx without the controls.